# Replicating each element n times while maintaining original order

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
A = [1 4 5 2 1 2]
```

How could I concisely replicate each element `n` times whilst maintaining the overall order e.g. if `n = 3`, the desired result would be:

```
[1 1 1 4 4 4 5 5 5 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Matlab R2015a** or higher use [**`repelem`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html?refresh=true)

```
n = 3;
u = repelem(A,n)
```

For older versions use [**`bsxfun`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?refresh=true)

```
n = 3;
u = bsxfun(@mtimes ,A(:).',ones(n,1))
u = u(:)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the repelem function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
reshape(repmat(a',[3 1]),[],1)
```